# Shell script to add values to a specific column

Tags: shell, awk

I have semicolon-separated columns, and I would like to add some characters to a specific column.

```
aaa;111;bbb
ccc;222;ddd
eee;333;fff
```

to the second column I want to add '@', so the output should be;

```
aaa;@111;bbb
ccc;@222;ddd
eee;@333;fff
```

I tried

```
awk -F';' -OFS=';' '{ $2 = "@" $2}1' file
```

It adds the character but removes all semicolons with space.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` to do your job:

```
# replaces just the first occurrence of ';', note the absence of `g` that 
# would have made it a global replacement
sed 's/;/;@/' file > file.out
```

or, to do it in place:

```
sed -i 's/;/;@/' file
```

Or, use `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{$2 = "@"$2}1' OFS=';' file
```

All the above commands result in the same output for your example file:

```
aaa;@111;bbb
ccc;@222;ddd
eee;@333;fff
```

Comment: OP only wants on the second column. This will change it, throughout the file

Comment: He wants the second column,  which is the first `;`.  See the desired output in his question.  I would love to see the `awk` solution from you.

Comment: Yes, tested all three solutions in my answer.  Do you see any issues?

Answer (score 1):

@atb: Try:
1st:

```
awk -F";" '{print $1 FS "@" $2 FS $3}'  Input_file
```

Above will work only when your Input_file has 3 fields only.

2nd:

```
awk -F";" -vfield=2 '{$field="@"$field} 1' OFS=";"   Input_file
```

Above code you could put any field number and could make it as per your request.
Here I am making field separator as ";" and then taking a variable named field which will have the field number in it and then that concatenating "@" in it's value and 1 is for making condition TRUE and not making and action so by default print action will happen of current line.

Answer (score 1):

You just misunderstood how to set variables. Change `-OFS` to `-v OFS`:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{ $2 = "@" $2 }1' file
```

but in reality you should set them both to the same value at one time:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} { $2 = "@" $2 }1' file
```